# An error occurred during local report processing. Scalable list: Index -1 outside the allowed range

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I use rdlc report with vb.net project. I need to print a barcode label in  custom paper 4.5cm x4.5cm.

I send Bindingsource to report and some row is work but some row has a problem.
It will error like these..

```
    An error occurred during local report processing. 
    Scalable list: Index -1 outside the allowed range.
```

[image]

But if I click on "Print Layout" buttons in toolbar. I's work and It's display on A4 paper which I don't need. 
[image]

How to resolve this problem. Help,me please?

Comment: Have you tried this?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2485396

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. We will resolve this problem by updating Cumulative update informatio, right? What is a Cumulative update information? How to update?

Answer (score 1):

> **SYMPTOMS**
>    Consider the following scenario:
>
> - You install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services (SSRS 2008 R2) on a computer.
> - You create a report that contains a `Tablix` control. This `Tablix` control has a text box.
> - You set the `HideDuplicates` property for the text box to a value that is in scope of the report. Therefore, the value of this property
>     is not set to `None`. You try to render or export the report by using
>     any hard-page-break renderer. For example, you try to use one of the
>     following renderers:
>
>   - PDF
>   - TIFF
>   - Print/Print Layout/Print Preview
>
> In this scenario, the report is not exported. Additionally, you
>   receive the following error message in a report design tool:
>
> ```
> An error occurred during local report processing.
> (processing): ScalableList: Index <id> outside the allowed range [0::<id-1>]
> ```
>
> Additionally, you receive the following error message in Report
>   Manager or the Report Server web service:
>
> ```
> An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. (rsInternalError)
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
> Exception Details: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details.(rsInternalError)
> Source Error: 
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
> ```
>
> **CAUSE**
>   This issue occurs because hard-page-break renderers throw an exception when the `HideDuplicates` property is not set to `None`
>   for a text box in a `Tablix` control.
>
> **RESOLUTION**
>   The fix for this issue was first released in Cumulative Update 6. For more information about how to obtain this cumulative update package for SQL Server 2008 R2, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>   [2489376 Cumulative Update package 6 for SQL Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2489376)

Source:
[FIX: Error when you use a hard page-break renderer to export a report in SSRS 2008 R2 if the HideDuplicates property is not set to None](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2485396)

---

The above article suggests that Cumulative Update 6 fixes this particular issue. "*Cumulative*" means that the update packes includes all the fixes from previous patches so there is no need to install older packages. This allows you to download the newest update package and it will include the fixes from the older update packages.

At this moment the newest hotfix package is [Cumulative update package 14](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2703280), so you can just download it from that link and it will include the fixes from update package 6 as well as newer fixes.

The following link contains an overview of all [the SQL Server 2008 R2 builds that were released after SQL Server 2008 R2 was released](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981356)

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. All textbox was set None in HideDuplicates property.

Comment: Now I can solve it. I just decrease a height of body area.
I can't explain but I 's work.

Comment: Same pitch "Fame th", Just increase the height and it's working fine. Thanks for the clue :)